# Terminal like view in Java Android

Tags: java, android, terminal, view, android-custom-view

i want to build terminal like view in Java. Like Termux have i only want view not shell. Please help me.

I tried Terminal View from Termux as a library but it builds sh shell i don't want sh or other shell. I only want view.

Comment: does something like this [Console](https://github.com/jraska/Console)

Comment: Writing a "console emulator" is not a simply task, many things must be considered(arguments, options, etc). I suggest you first try to develp it just like a java application, then put it on your android app. If you struggle, try looking fore some console project online like @VishalBeep told you and use that as a base.